# 412 gmail api error on emailjs email services

Tags: reactjs, email

I am getting 412 Gmail_API: Request had insufficient authentication scopes while trying to configure service in Email JS. I don't know what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please turn off the 2-factor authentication mode in your Gmail account, go back to emailjs refresh it and try again. You will be good to go.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.